# Invocation of C++20 template lambda gives parsing error

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

Consider the following C++20 code in which a template lambda calls a template function.

The compilation fails with 'no match for operator <' at line `bar<1>(2.0);` (with latest GCC/MSVC, C++20 enabled).

How do I make it work?

```
template<int n>
void foo(double m) {
    std::cout << n << m << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto bar = []<int n>(double m) {
        foo<n>(m);
    };

    bar<1>(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bar.operator()<1>(2.0);`

Comment: Keep in mind that `bar<1>(2.0)` already means `operator>(operator<(bar, 1), 2.0)` and that `bar` is not the name of a template.